# SQL query all ID's not equal to session ID

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Having trouble getting all match results for a particular session ID. I want to not include the session ID but include all other results for now (then will add conditions in php). I am just getting the rows for one ID (128). So if the session ID is 125, it excludes this but only picks up 128 which is first in the records but after three 128 entries (for three questions) is an ID 127 that does not get included. When printing the count it tells me 3, there should be 6. So I assume the problem is within the function.

Any ideas how to push this through? Here's my function:

```
function quiz_match($user_id, $question_id ,$choice_id){
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT * FROM `question_answers` WHERE `user_id` <> $user_id AND `question_id` = $question_id AND `choice_id` = $choice_id" );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rows[] = $row;
        if (count($rows)>0){
            foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
                $u_id = $value['user_id'];
                $array_q= [];
                array_push($array_q, $u_id, $value['question_id'], $value['choice_id']); 
                //$result = count($array_q);
                //echo "number of rows " . $result;
            } return $array_q;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

*For the array [0] is the ID, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wXfq.png) question id and [2] choice id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from bad indenting, causing you to not realize where you were throwing the code: whether it was in the while loop, the if, the foreach, would have been totally a mystery.

Therefore, you had your if-statement inside your while loop, and thus were returning from within the while loop, rather than adding all the rows to the `$rows` array and then doing your if-statement.

You also would have been resetting the `$array_q` to empty, if you weren't returning prematurely, so that line needs to be moved out of the `foreach` loop.

You also have no MySQL connection being passed into the function! You're treating `$_POST['x']` as if its a MySQL connection, and there's no way that it is!

```
function quiz_match($connection, $user_id, $question_id ,$choice_id)
{
    //there is no way the next commented out line even works!
    //$query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT * FROM `question_answers` WHERE `user_id` <> $user_id AND `question_id` = $question_id AND `choice_id` = $choice_id" );

    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `question_answers` WHERE `user_id` <> $user_id AND `question_id` = $question_id AND `choice_id` = $choice_id");
    $rows = array(); //you should add this too
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    if (count($rows)>0)
    {
        $array_q = array(); //this should be here, not in the foreach loop
        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) 
        {
            $u_id = $value['user_id'];
            //$array_q= []; //wrong place for this
            array_push($array_q, $u_id, $value['question_id'], $value['choice_id']); 
        }
        //$result = count($array_q);
        //echo "number of rows " . $result;
        return $array_q;
     }
     return false;
}
```